# How should I instantiate from constructor?

Tags: c#, class, call, instantiation

I'm just in constructor of JatekElem.class and I'd like to call a method from JatekTer.class, where the parameter is a JatekElem object. How should I do this?

I tried to change the required parameter in method Felvetel(); from that class type to 2 int types and a JatekTer.class type, but I don't know, this idea wasn't the best...

```
class JatekElem
{
   int x;
   int y;
   JatekTer ter;

   public JatekElem(int x, int y, JatekTer jatekter)
   {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      ter = jatekter;

      JatekTer jt = new JatekTer();
      jt.Felvetel(/*MISSING PARAMETER*/);    //I'd like to use the fields,
   }                                     //which I just gave value (x, y, ter)
}

class JatekTer
{
   [...]

   public void Felvetel(JatekElem obj)
   {
      [...]
   }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you have a circular dependency here, it's a clear sign that your code is organised poorly. I'd suggest rethinking this completely.

Comment: just do jt.Felvetel(this);

Comment: Also, you are passing in a `JatekTer` in the constructor, why are you creating a new one?

Comment: Referencing an object which hasn't completed being constructed is *probably* a bad idea.  Why do you think you need to?  The contrived example doesn't really demonstrate what you're trying to accomplish.  But from what it does demonstrate, passing a not-yet-constructed instance of `JatekElem` to a method on an entirely different object is likely to cause problems down the line.